# Generating data for training in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My training set is really quite large. The entire thing takes up about 120GB of RAM and so I can't even generate the numpy.zeros() array to store the data.

From what I've seen, using a generator works well when the entire dataset is already loaded into an array but then is incrementally fed into the network and then deleted afterwards.

Is it alright for the generator to create the arrays, insert the data, load the data into the network, delete the data? Or will that whole process take too long and I should be doing something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to load the whole data at once, you can load just as much as your batch needs. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569938/memory-issues-using-keras-convolutional-network/44593430#44593430).

Comment: Hi Phoebe, I've been attempting to do exactly that recently however my results are getting massively worse and it seems to take longer to train if I ever want to get the same type of results? Is this to be expected?

Comment: This can happen when your batch is not a good representation of your data (noisy gradients). You can load more data than the batch size, stratified it, and then train, or play with the batch_size until getting similar results. [More Info](https://www.quora.com/Intuitively-how-does-batch-size-impact-a-convolutional-network-training)

Comment: I see. I'm using batch_size of 1024, epochs=4, steps_per_epoch=500 which I figured were quite reasonable estimates. It's a character based model and the training data is 15 million characters long. 

As I've understood it, each epoch will take 500 batches and each batch will have 1024 data points and each of those data points will be 100 characters long. As I understand this is just hyperparameter tuning until I get something good? Is there any heuristic here as to what to use? 

I'll test out a ton of measures and reply here further if it's no good. Thanks!

Comment: well, lower batch_sizes would intuitively need more epochs to convege to the same minima as larger batch_sizes, so I would increment the number of epochs. Also, relate your number of steps to your batch_size with this function: `steps_per_epoch = len(train_set)//batch_size + 1`. You can also make your batch_size way bigger than 1024. If your computer has at least 16GB, try with 8192 or even more.

Comment: Hopefully this doesn't sound silly, but isn't my training set generated in the generator? So how would I have access to this variable from here?

Comment: you know how big your complete training set is, you just do not load it all at once. There are no 'silly questions'. If you ask (respectfully), your answer should be answered. That is what this community is for. Also, have you looked at the distributions of your datasets? Are you sure you need 120GB of characters?

Comment: Okay, great thank you for that. I think I understand how that works but I'm still getting extremely bad results and I'm 95% sure it's the way that I'm feeding my data. Ultimately my "yield" should be just my X_train and Y_train and if those are appropriate then there should really be no issue with the model training right?

Comment: If your batches represent your whole set, theory says there should be no difference. But if your data are chars, a batch_size of 8192 or 16284 should be a really considerable amount of data for a training set.

Comment: Hmm, I've gone in and fixed all the "bugs" that I've found and it makes intuitive sense to me now. However, my model is producing not a single word even though it claims to be training. Could I show you the last bits of my model in a private chat and you can tell me if it's obviously wonky?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147848/discussion-between-tryingtolearn-and-regina-fallangi).