# GridSearch in Keras + TensorFlow resulting in Resource exhausted

Tags: memory-management, out-of-memory, gpu, keras, tensorflow

I know that this error is recurrent and I understand what can cause it.
For example, running this model with 163 images of 150x150 gives me the error (however it's not clear to me why setting batch_size Keras still seems to try to allocate all images at a time in the GPU):

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(6, 6), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, padding='same', name='b1_conv'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='b1_poll'))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(6, 6), activation='relu', padding='same', name='b2_conv'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='b2_pool'))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=(6, 6), activation='relu', padding='same', name='b3_conv'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), name='b3_pool'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', name='fc1'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(500, activation='relu', name='fc2'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(n_targets, activation='softmax', name='prediction'))
    model.compile(optimizer=optim, loss='categorical_crossentropy',  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Given that, I reduced the images size to 30x30 (which resulted in an accuracy drop, as expected). However, running grid search in this model Resource exhausted.

```
model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, verbose=0)

# grid initial weight, batch size and optimizer
sgd  = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0005)
rms  = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0005)
adag = optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.0005)
adad = optimizers.Adadelta(lr=0.0005)
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005)
adamm = optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.0005)
nadam = optimizers.Nadam(lr=0.0005)

optimizers = [sgd, rms, adag, adad, adam, adamm, nadam]
init = ['glorot_uniform', 'normal', 'uniform', 'he_normal']
batches = [32, 64, 128]
param_grid = dict(optim=optimizers, batch_size=batches, init=init)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid)
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

# summarize results
print("Best: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

I wonder if it's possible to "clean" things before each combination used by the grid search (not sure if I made myself clear, this is all new to me).

**EDIT**

Using the `fit_generator` also gives me the same error:

```
def generator(features, labels, batch_size):
    # Create empty arrays to contain batch of features and labels#
    batch_features = np.zeros((batch_size, size, size, 1))
    batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size, n_targets))
    while True:
        for i in range(batch_size):
            # choose random index in features
            index = np.random.choice(len(features),1)
            batch_features[i] = features[index]
            batch_labels[i] = labels[index]
        yield batch_features, batch_labels

sgd  = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.0005)
rms  = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0005)
adag = optimizers.Adagrad(lr=0.0005)
adad = optimizers.Adadelta(lr=0.0005)
adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005)
adamm = optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.0005)
nadam = optimizers.Nadam(lr=0.0005)

optim = [rms, adag, adad, adam, adamm, nadam]
init = ['normal', 'uniform', 'he_normal']

combinations = [(a, b) for a in optim for b in init]
for combination in combinations:
    init  = combination[1]
    optim = combination[0]
    model = create_model(init=init, optim=optim)
    model.fit_generator(generator(X_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
                        steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0] // 32,
                        epochs=100, verbose=0, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
    scores = model.model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print("%s: %.2f%% Model %s %s" % (model.model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100, optim, init))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should work with generators + `yield`, they discard from the memory the data they already used. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569938/memory-issues-using-keras-convolutional-network/44593430#44593430) to a similar question.

Comment: And how do I use it with GridSearch?

Comment: GridSearch does not seem to take in generators, but you can simulate a GridSearch with a for loop and saving the models. The cross validation even shuffling your dataset after every loop. A quick example would be something like this: https://gist.github.com/lfcj/c02980dbf8c390cd470e840b460a418f

Comment: This solution gives me ResourceExhaustedError after running some searches.

Comment: Would you mind posting your generator? You have only included the training part.

Comment: Of course, just did it, @regina_fallangi. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You call `model.fit_generator(X_train, y_train)`, but you don't use the generator to create `X_train` and `y_train`. You do not use the generator, as far as I see in your code. That may be why you still get the same Error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the tensorflow session after each run of training/evaluation

```
K.clear_session()
```

with `K` as the tensorflow backend.

Comment: Have done that and than the error changes to something like `ValueError: Tensor("Variable_12:0", shape=(64,), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("rho_4/read:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).`

Comment: Am I missing the correct way to use this? I've put K.clear_session() after the last line of the loop.

Comment: @pceccon I think the reason is that you reference the same optimizer through all searches of your grid. Keep in mind that the optimizer is just a part of the symbolic graph, thus you have to recreate the optimizer the same way you did it with the model.

Comment: But since I'm looping over the optimizers, this doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Is it possible to create optimizers (specifying its parameters) passing its name as string? Otherwise I don't see how to do a gridsearch and not have Resource Exhausted Error.

Comment: @pceccon the second you put the optimizer into the model, it becomes part of the graph. If you clear the session, the graph ceases while the same optimizer instance is still holding onto the graph you just cleared. Thus the unbound tensor error (I guess RHO is a parameter of rmsprop).

Comment: @pceccon just treat the parameters as additional hyperparameters in the grid and then just create an instance of optimizer X with these parameters. It's called a factory pattern, check out more here: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html

Comment: Sorry, @ThomasJungblut, but are you talking to do this using the fit_generator approach?

Comment: @pceccon this is absolutely unrelated to the data and generator as this only touches the way you build the model.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry. Just didn't get how to use this properly. Thanks.